# Team Foundation - how to get files that are only part of a solution

Tags: tfs

We use TFS as our source control repository. As a result we have files that are stored in the tree but are NOT part of the main solution. 
During the build process I use the following command:

> tf get $/mysolutionPath /recursive /all
>   /noprompt

This returns all files even those that are not part of the solution or its projects. I wonder if there is a way to get only files/projects that are only part of a specific solution, similar to Visual Studio's "Open Solution from source control" option.

Comment: You could edit your workspace to cloak the folders / files that are not in the solution - this is assuming you don't want to ever get the files in that workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because this is a feature implemented by the visual studio source control plugin to TFS. It uses the project's file list to request the files it is interested in (which is to say only files that are part of the solution).